# Call jobs on demand

Tags: docker, kubernetes

We have a docker container which is a CLI application, it runs, does it s things and exits.

I got the assignment to put this into kubernetes but that containers can not be deployed as it exits and then is considered a crashloop.

So the next question is if it can be put in a job. The job runs and gets restarted every time a request comes in over the proxy. Is that possible? Can job be restarted externally with different parameters in kubernetes?

Comment: Can you wrap this in a long-running task that accepts jobs from a message queue like RabbitMQ and then does them?  Or, can you embed this subprocess directly in the parent application that calls it?

Comment: Do you just want to spawn a job on demand/request, or do you want sth like serverless/FaaS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the next question is if it can be put in a job.

If it is supposed to just run once, a [Kubernetes Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) is a good fit.

> The job runs and gets restarted every time a request comes in over the proxy. Is that possible?

This can not easyli be done without external add-ons. Consider using [Knative](https://knative.dev/) for this.

> Can job be restarted externally with different parameters in kubernetes?

Not easyli, you need to interact with the Kubernetes API, to create a new Job for this, if I understand you correctly. One way to do this, is to have a Job with `kubectl`-image and proper RBAC-permissions on the ServiceAccount to create new jobs - but this will involve some latency since it is two jobs.